# Prolog, how to add a clause if the base case is accepted

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I am new to Prolog.  I am trying to write a predicate that is true when there is a path from X to Z, including X to Y and Y to Z.

For example

```
    foo(b,Y,[[a,b],[b,c],[b,d],[d,e]]).
    Y = c ;
    Y = d ;
    Y = e ;
```

I can write the code which is true when there is a path from X to Y but can't figure out how to add the code to get from Y to Z if the base case is true.

```
    foo(Y, X, [Y, X]).
    foo(Y, X, [Head|_]) :- foo(Y, X, Head).
    foo(Y, X, [_|Tail]) :- foo(Y, X, Tail).
```

Comment: There is some confusion in the 3rd argument  in your clauses. The heads of your clauses all indicate the 3rd argument to be a simple list. But then  you call `foo(Y, X, Head)` where `Head` is  a list  *element*,, not a list, presumably. So that's probably not what you want. The semantics of `foo(Y, X, [Head|_]) :- foo(Y, X, Head).` are a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming you want general transitive closure)

```
conn(XYss, X, Y) :-
   member([X,Y], XYss).

foo2(X, Y, XYss) :-
   closure(conn(XYss), X, Y).
```

using [`closure/3`](/q/26946133/772868). Alternatively, using `library(lambda)`:

```
foo2(X, Y, XYss) :-
   closure({XYss}+\Xi^Yi^member([Xi,Yi], XYss), X, Y).
```

And taking your question literally, you only want:

```
foo3(X, Y, XYss) :-
   member([X,Y], XYss).
foo3(X, Z, XYss) :-
   member([X,Y], XYss),
   member([Y,Z], XYss).
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer has helped me to improve my understanding of Prolog